# Day and month swapping only for single digits in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

I have written an SSIS integration which fetches an employee and his expiry date. All the data is flowing correctly; however when a single digit day and month is present in expiry date, the destination column swaps the month and day (when the date has double unit for months or days its fine).

Example:

```
      07/08/2016   to  2016-07-08     WRONG

      15/03/2016   to  2016-03-15     CORRECT
```

Comment: Where is your data coming from? Is it from SQL or some other source?

Comment: Data coming from SQL

Comment: The first thing I would check is the regional settings on the machine running the SSIS package.

Comment: Seems fine. What could be another option?

Comment: Your package will have a LocaleId property, which can affect regional settings. Check that it is set to what you would expect.

Comment: How can I check that.. sorry I am new to SSIS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139316/discussion-between-greg-the-incredulous-and-shivang).

Comment: what is the columns datatypes, (source and destination)? date is stored as varchar or datetime?

Comment: There's not enough detail in your question. You need to post the datatypes of everything (source, target, inside the data flow). If everything is a date data type you should have no problems. But if you have made the mistake of storing dates in varchars then you need to fix that very soon.

Comment: If everything is a date as it should be, then regional settings and formats are completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

since your date are in dd/MM/yyyy and you are in trying to convert it into datetime,so problem occurs.
I think this more safe,

```
declare @jk varchar(20)='07/08/2016'

select right(@jk,4)+'-'+substring(@jk,charindex('/',@jk)+1,2)+'-'+substring(@jk,1,2)
```